# Why 1.5\fill is 0pt

Tags: spacing

A `\fill` is `0pt plus 1fill` by definition (in LaTeX kernel), but why `1.5\fill` gives `0.0pt` (the same for other multipliers)?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\skip_log:n {       \fill }
\skip_log:n { 1     \fill }
\skip_log:n { 1.5   \fill }
\skip_log:n { 1pt + \fill }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
> \fill =0.0pt plus 1.0fill.
> 1\fill =0.0pt.
> 1.5\fill =0.0pt.
> 1pt+\fill =1.0pt plus 1.0fill.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose `\foo` is a skip register; then the operation `<factor>\foo` can be performed, but since it's only defined on `\dimen` registers, the `<skip>` is converted to a `<dimen>` by removing the stretch and shrink components.

Look at the syntax for `<dimen>` and for `<glue>` on pages 270 and 271 of the TeXbook.

The `\skip_log:n` operation allows for operations on glue internally using `\glueexpr` (which is essentially an unnamed skip register) and finally using `\showthe` (which doesn't care about the nature of the following token).

If you do instead `\skip_log:n { \fill*3/2 }` you will get

```
> \fill *3/2=0.0pt plus 1.5fill.
```

because scaling (with integers) is allowed in a `<glue expr>`.